# Repetitive Tasks with bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have a php console app and an Ubuntu server. I'm executing the app with this basic command:

```
php app.php
```

I want to execute it repetitively, but cronjobs is not suitable for me. Instead, I want it to execute such that when app.php finishes working it will be executed again immediately (like an infinity loop), rather than being executed again every X minutes. 
So I made this bash script:

```
while true; do
php app.php
done
```

this solves my problem, but the usage of `while true` seems evil. Is it possible to stop this bash script, if necessary? Or can you tell me a better way to do this?

(app.php file , fetches a long list of website URLs and their content. It's like a web spider. I connect to the server via ssh , execute bash script with nohup, and then close terminal. )

Comment: To exit a while loop, use `break`, or if there are nested loops use break with the number of loops, e.g. `break 2` for 2 while loops. You can break on a particular condition, by using an if statement inside the while loop. On what condition do you want the script to break out of the loop?

Comment: @Mik , `On what condition do you want the script to break out of the loop?`it can be lots of things, for example maybe server will be overheat, or we will want to go maintaince, or somethings like these. Because of this i can't use if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example about what you can do:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon time 0 min 0; fi

    keypress=''
    while [ "x$keypress" = "x" ]; do
        #do something... in your case:
        php app.php
        #end of 'do something'

        read keypress
    done

    if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi

    echo "You pressed '$keypress' for pause."
    read -p 'Press [Enter] key to continue or [Ctrl+C] to finish...'
done
```

To pause you can press any key without <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To continue you must to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To finish you must to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

---

If you run the script in background using:

```
nohup <name_of_script> &
```

you can stop it using the following commands:

```
ps -ef | grep <name_of_script> #to find the pid of the running script
kill -9 <pid_of_your_running_script>
```

Comment: This script is remarkably similar to [this one here at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297638/bash-how-to-end-infinite-loop-with-any-key-pressed), but perhaps it is a coincidence?

Comment: @Mik Do you have a better idea to pause a while loop?

Comment: See my comment under the OP's question, re using `break` to escape from a while loop, but I'm not sure on what condition the OP wants the script to break from the while loop.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu , i will connect to server via ssh , execute command with nohup, and then close terminal. So this answer won't work for me.

Comment: @Eray Well, you didn't specified this in your question.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu , you're right. My mistake. But i said, it will executed again again (forever) , i can't open terminal window forever :)

Comment: @Eray See my new edits

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use your script and when you want to stop it you open a terminal and:
1. Get the pid of script: `ps -ef | grep "mycript"`
2. Terminate `kill -s 15 PID` or kill `kill -s 9 PID` it.